# Difference in Git Repositories in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

I have two git repositories in a project in Azure DevOps. Why do they display differently? One has a red icon, the other a black icon. What is the difference?

[image: Two different icons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The black icon is a fork.

**What's in a fork?**

> A fork starts with all the contents of its upstream (original)
> repository. When you create a fork, you can choose whether to include
> all branches or limit to only the default branch. None of the
> permissions, policies, or build pipelines are applied. The new fork
> acts as if someone cloned the original repository, then pushed to a
> new, empty repository. After a fork has been created, new files,
> folders, and branches are not shared between the repositories unless a
> PR carries them along.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) more info.

Comment: Is there an easy way to convert the forked repo into a normal one? I.e., not have the relationship back to the original repo?

Comment: Do you want to use only the regular? there are changes in the fork that doesn't exist in the original?

Comment: Yes, there are changes. I don't want to have a reference to the original -- it's in another project altogether.

Comment: You can just create a new regular repo, add it as a remote in the fork and push.